# AppSync loading incorrect resolver for field

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

AppSync appears to be loading the incorrect resolver template for some fields of nested objects. Also, it appears to only happen when the nested object has a field with the same name as a field on the parent object.

I've included an example below because I think that might be the best way to explain the issue. As you can see, the `id` fields for the nested objects are not being resolved correctly.

Each type, Task, User, List, and Tag, have a resolver for their `id` field because the data for each has a prefix on the id field. For example, Task.id has a resolver that returns `$context.source.task_id` and User.id has a resolver that returns `$context.source.user_id`. Same for List and Tag.

What appears to be happening is AppSync is loading the `id` resolver template for the parent type. You can see that this is the case for `task.owner.id`, where `owner` is a User but the `id` gets resolved as `"$context.source.task_id"`. Same for `task.list.id` where `list` is a List. Again we can see this for `task.tags[0].owner.id`. `owner` is once again a User except this time the parent is a Tag so `task.tags[0].owner.id` is resolved as `"$context.source.tag_id"`. These three example show that the problem is not with a particular type since User and List are behaving the same when they are nested in a Task. Also, we can see that the issue is not with Task since User is behaving similarly when nested in a Tag. Lastly, we can see that `task.tags[1].owner.id` actually behaves correctly. This indicates that the issue only presents itself on first execution.

At this point I strongly suspect this is a bug with AppSync however, I'm not 100% on that. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Am I doing something terribly wrong?

**Example**

Query

```
{
  task(id: "task-123") {
    id,
    title,
    owner {
      id,
      username,
    },
    list {
      id,
      name,
    },
    tags {
      id,
      name,
      owner {
        id,
        username,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "task": {
      "id": "task-123",
      "title": "First Task",
      "owner": {
        "id": "$context.source.task_id",
        "username": "tom"
      },
      "list": {
        "id": "$context.source.task_id",
        "name": "Inbox"
      },
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "tag-123",
          "name": "one",
          "owner": {
            "id": "$context.source.tag_id",
            "username": "tom"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "tag-234",
          "name": "two",
          "owner": {
            "id": "user-123",
            "username": "tom"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Task Schema

```
type Task {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    owner: User!
    list: List
    tags: [Tag]
}
```

User Schema

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
}
```

List Schema

```
type List {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}
```

Tag Schema

```
type Tag {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    owner: User!
}
```

Task Data

```
{
    task_id: "task-123",
    title: "First Task",
    owner_id: "user-123",
    list_id: "list-123",
    tags: [
        "tag-123",
        "tag-234"
    ]
}
```

User Data

```
{
    user_id: "user-123",
    username: "tom"
}
```

List Data

```
{
    list_id: "list-123",
    name: "Inbox"
}
```

Tag Data

```
{
    tag_id: "tag-123",
    name: "one",
    owner_id: "user-123"
}

{
    tag_id: "tag-234",
    name: "two",
    owner_id: "user-123"
}
```

Example id resolver (User)

Request Mapping Template

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "payload": "$context.source.user_id"
}
```

Response Mapping Template

```
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

The id resolvers for the other types are very similar

It may also be worth noting that I created different None Data Sources for each type, Task, User, List, and Tag. The id resolver for each type is using their respective None Data Source.

Comment: I think this is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065749/dynamodb-appsync-field-resolvers-timing-out I am thinking the work around is just to name all fields differently. Which is stupid. Is this a bug? It seems like it. Whats the best place to submits AppSync bugs?