# DynamoDB AppSync field resolvers timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

So I have the schema below. If I try to query data off this schema AppSync will time out saying 'NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'

```
type Model {
    PartitionKey: ID!
    SortKey: ID!
    Name: String
    Version: Int
    FBX: String
    # ms since epoch
    CreatedAt: AWSTimestamp
    Description: String
    Tags: [Tag]
}

type ImageSet {
    PartitionKey: ID!
    SortKey: ID!
    Name: String
    CreatedAt: AWSTimestamp
    Description: String
    Tags: [String]
}
```

Now, if I change 'Name' in the model to 'ModelName' then queries on that will work. If I change 'Name' in ImageSet to 'SetName' then queries on that will work.

What is going on with this? What is wrong with the 'Name' field name? 'Description' and 'CreatedAt' do not have this issue.

> Edit
>
> Actually I am encountering this happening with other fields in the
>   schema as well. Please help.
>
> I do have resolvers attached to specific fields. Removing them does
>   solve the problem. Am I not supposed to attach revolvers to specific
>   fields or is something else wrong?

-

> Edit 2
>
> This really does seem to only occur if the name of a field is shared
>   between different schema objects, is that not allowed!?

Comment: To clarify - you're saying you have nested resolvers? A resolver on a field inside the type returned by a hypothetical query? If so, AppSync just rolled out an update that might have fixed this. Can you try again?

Comment: Hello, are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: As of like 6 pm yesterday it was doing this. Did the update come out since then?

Comment: So I just tried doing a nested query again, and it seemed to not have the issue. Was this really fixed in the past 12 hours?

Comment: Yes this was fixed quickly after being detected