# Returning Appsync GraphQL type that also has field resolvers

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I would like to return the ImageSet type from the AddImageSet mutation. But I seem to be unable to do this because each field on my ImageSet type has it's own resolver, which is overwriting the resolver mapping template.

Schema:

```
type ImageSet {
    SetKey: ID
    SetName: String
    SetCreatedAt: AWSTimestamp
    SetDescription: String
    SetTags: [Tag]
}

type Mutation {
    AddImageSet(setName: String!, setDescription: String): ImageSet
}
```

Here is the mutation:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "PartitionKey" : { "S" : "ImageSet" },
        "SortKey" : { "S" : "ImageSet-$util.autoId()" }
    },
    "attributeValues" : {
        "Name": { "S" : "${context.arguments.setName}" },
        "Description": { "S" : "${context.arguments.setDescription}" },
        "CreatedAt": { "N" : $util.time.nowEpochSeconds() },
    }
}
```

and the response mapping template

```
{
    "SetKey" : "$context.result.SortKey",
    "SetName" : "$context.result.Name",
    "SetCreatedAt" : $context.result.CreatedAt,
    "SetDescription" : "$context.result.Description"
}
```

When I run this, the object returned by AddImageSet mutation has every field set as null, because the field resolvers are overwriting the response mapping template of the AddImageSet mutation.

I have solved this by creating a duplicate 'ImageSetResult' type, just without resolvers attached to the field. Then if the AddImageSet Mutation returns that, everything is just fine. But these seems kind of redundant.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior in GraphQL. If you have a resolver on **ImageSet.SetKey** and your **Mutation.AddImageSet** mutation returns an object of type **ImageSet**, the resolver of every field listed in the selection set will be invoked. The values returned by **Mutation.AddImageSet** will be overwritten by whatever values are returned by the child resolvers.

To add more context, the value that you are returning from the **Mutation.AddImageSet** response mapping template will be the value of **$ctx.source** when you are in the **ImageSet.SetKey/SetName/SetCreatedAt** resolvers. From those resolvers you could then do something like this:

```
#if( $ctx.source.SetKey ) "$ctx.source.SetKey" #else .. whatever SetKey does .. #end
```

Is there a reason you need resolvers on SetKey/SetName/etc? If the object is already being returned by **Mutation.AddImageSet** or **Query.AddImageSet** etc then you do not need resolvers on that type.

Another note. Is there a reason you want the names **ImageSet.SetName** instead of just **ImageSet.Name** which is how you storing it in DynamoDB? This seems to be adding a lot of complexity where you can probably avoid it.

Comment: I am using SetName instead of just Name because of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065749/dynamodb-appsync-field-resolvers-timing-out?noredirect=1#comment91088095_52065749 I guess it's an AppsSync bug with nested revolvers. Also my set up here is much more intricate than what my initial post implies. I have a many to many relationship in DynamoDB and types are getting arrays of their nested types via nested queries. In some cases 'SetKey' is the PK and in some cases it's the SK.

Comment: Gotcha. Yes that issue should not be a problem any longer.